# Como organizar um Array por ordem de Data?

Tags: c#, array

Estou querendo organizar um array por ordem de data Crescente. Estava pensando em cortar as partes usando a barra `(/)` e comparar com as outras partes, mas não sei se é o melhor modo de se fazer.

Preciso organizar o array abaixo:

```
List<string> datas = new List<string>();
```

> 0 [02/05/2018]
>
> 1 [01/04/2018]
>
> 2 [07/03/2018]
>
> 3 [06/02/2018]
>
> 4 [09/01/2018]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `Linq` para converter a lista de strings para uma lista de datas e ordena-los.

## Exemplo

```
var orderedDates = datas.OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x,"dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

<sub>[Veja funcionando no dot.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0szEd0)</sub>

Comment: Tua resposta tá certa, mas fica como dica converter a string para data apenas no `OrderBy`. Isso porque provavelmente o AP deve querer simular que a estrutura se mantém a mesma.

Comment: Bem observado @LINQ, vou adicionar à resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Segue o código abaixo, espero ter ajudado

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Populando sua lista
        var datas = new List<string>() {
            "02/05/2018",
            "01/04/2018",
            "07/03/2018",
            "06/02/2018",
            "09/01/2018",
        };

        //Ordenando datas com OrderBy e atribuindo o resultado em "datasOrdemCrescente"
        var datasOrdemCrescente = datas.OrderBy(c => Convert.ToDateTime(c));

        //Imprimir resultado datasOrdemCrescente
        foreach (var item in datasOrdemCrescente)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("---------------");

        //Ordenando datas com OrderByDescending e atribuindo o resultado em "datasOrdemDecrescente"
        var datasOrdemDecrescente = datas.OrderByDescending(c => Convert.ToDateTime(c));

        //Imprimir resultado datasOrdemDecrescente
        foreach (var item in datasOrdemDecrescente)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```